# Efficient way to get index of every element in array greater than some value

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, c++20

I have a (quite large) standard `C++` array of type `double`, with `~50,000,000` rows and `20` columns. The array is filled with random data, according to some Gaussian distribution (if that's of any use in answering this question).

I've written an algorithm to solve a problem using this array. A significant part of this algorithm's time is spent iterating, row by row (and sometimes over the same row more than once) and returning, for each row, the index of every element in that row such that the absolute value of that element exceeds some value (also of type `double`).

Unfortunately, the algorithm is quite slow. As it's rather large, and the problem being solved is a bit complex for simply dumping the code here on SO, I'd like to start by tacking this issue. What is the most efficient (or, at least, a more efficient way) to grab the index of every element in a row of a multidimensional array?

**What I've tried:**

I've tried simply iterating through each row (with an iterator), passing each value to `fabs()`, and using `std::distance()` to get the index. I then store it in an `std::set()` (I don't care much about how the indices are stored, unless that is a significant speed factor, so long as they are "easily accessible").

I.e.:

```
                for(auto it = row.begin(); it != row.end(); ++it){

                        auto &element = *it;

                        if(fabs(element) >= threshold){
                                cache.insert(std::distance(row.begin(), it));
                        }
                }
```

I've also tried using `std::find_if`, and similarly through `std::range`. Neither gave measurable speed improvements (admittedly, I haven't used particularly scientific benchmarks, however I'm going for a visibly noticeable improvement).

I.e. something like this:

```
    auto exceeds_thresh = [](double x){ return x > threshold}

    it = ranges::find_if(row, exceeds_thresh);
    while(it != end(row)){
        resuts.emplace_back(distance(begin(row), it));
        it = ranges::find_if(std::next(it), std::end(row), exceeds_thresh)
    }
```

*Note that, by efficiency, I'm focusing on speed*

---

Here, `11.3, 9.8, 17.5` satisfy the condition, so their indices `1,3,6` should be printed. Note that, in practice, each array is a row in a far larger array (as above), and with far greater number of elements in each row:

```
double row_of_array[5] = {1.4, 11.3, 4.2, 9.8, 0.1, 3.2, 17.5};
double threshold = 8;

for(auto it = row_of_array.begin(); it != row_of_array.end(); ++it){
    auto &element = *it;

    if(fabs(element) > threshold){
        std::cout << std::distance(row_of_array.begin(), it) << "\n";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to add the c++ tag to C++ questions. As a regular asker of C++ questions, you should know by now that this will make your question much more visible.

Comment: Don't use `set` use `unorderedset` unless you care about ordering. It's much faster

Comment: Also consider specifying [`std::execution::parallel_unsequenced_policy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find#Parameters) when you're iterating that many elements

Comment: A [mre] would be helpful

Comment: @AlanBirtles Added. I left it out originally as I'm not sure it's going to be particularly helpful here.

Comment: How far is the code you've posted, how fast do you need it to be? I assume this is some code contest problem? You'll probably find your approach to the problem is wrong and there is some algorithmic shortcut which you are missing

Comment: How many elements do you expect to be above the threshold? If it's any significant fraction of the total, those `insert`s are absolutely horrendous because they are unhinted (constructing `cache` for one row is `O(n + m log m)` in `n` the number of elements and `m` the number of "accepted" elements), but if you pass `cache.end()` to `cache.insert` as a hint that should fall to `O(n + m)`, since the indices are inserted in ascending order.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for the suggestions, however this isn't a contest problem. Insofar as speed, the goal is to cut execution time of the entire algorithm in half (if possible), so significant speed improvement here is the goal.

Comment: It's difficult to offer optimisation tips without knowing what you're whole problem is

Comment: e.g sorting your array would allow you to use a binary search

Comment: @KeithMadison I still don't see a [mcve]. All your code snippets access `row`, but there is no definition for it. For example `std::distance` has different complexity for `vector` iterator and `list` iterator.

Comment: `std::vector` seems more appropriate than `std::set` to store results.

Comment: Do you really need to store result, is filter view good enough (how many resulting index? how costly is your filter? can you mutate the input matrix (remove_erase idiom might fit)? ...

Comment: @WernerHenze Apologies. I changed `row` to `row_of_array`, for clarity, but forgot to change it everywhere. Fixed.

Comment: @Jarod42 I use `std::set` here due to the fact that it automatically "removes" duplicates, which is quite useful in the another portion of the algorithm. What I more-or-less end up doing is iterating over some number of rows, and for each row grabbing the index of every element greater than the threshold. After every, say, `1000` rows, I get the size of `std::set` to determine how many *unique* columns in the multidimensional array had an element exceeding the threshold, within that `1000` rows. So, I don't want to, say, count coln `3` twice.

Comment: @Jarod42 Some other things go on, including jumping back and forth row-wise in the multidimensional array depending on the # of unique columns with an element exceeding the threshold (i.e. depending on the size of `std::set`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try loop unrolling

```cpp
double row_of_array[]      = {1, 11, 4, 9, 0, 3, 17};
constexpr double threshold = 8;
std::vector<int> results;
results.reserve(20);
for(int i{}, e = std::ssize(row_of_array); i < e; i += 4)
{
   if(std::abs(row_of_array[i]) > threshold)
      results.push_back(i);
   if(i + 1 < e && std::abs(row_of_array[i + 1]) > threshold)
      results.push_back(i + 1);
   if(i + 2 < e && std::abs(row_of_array[i + 2]) > threshold)
      results.push_back(i + 2);
   if(i + 3 < e && std::abs(row_of_array[i + 3]) > threshold)
      results.push_back(i + 3);
}
```

**EDIT**:

or the riskier

```cpp
double row_of_array[20]    = {1, 11, 4, 9, 0, 3, 17};
constexpr double threshold = 8;
std::vector<int> results;
results.reserve(20);
static_assert(std::ssize(row_of_array) % 4 == 0, "only works for mul of 4");
for(int i{}, e = std::ssize(row_of_array); i < e; i += 4)
{
   if(std::abs(row_of_array[i]) > threshold) results.push_back(i);
   if(std::abs(row_of_array[i + 1]) > threshold) results.push_back(i + 1);
   if(std::abs(row_of_array[i + 2]) > threshold) results.push_back(i + 2);
   if(std::abs(row_of_array[i + 3]) > threshold) results.push_back(i + 3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Hadn't thought of this, I'll try it and see what happens.